# How to print below xml code in XML?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

> print this xml in xml format ?

```
'<availabilityResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <hotel id="123456789">
     <offers>
     <offer total="435.00" currency="EUR">
     </offer>
     </offers>
     </hotel>
     <errors>
     <error type=”E002”>Unknown hotel identifier: 32165487</error>
     <error type=”E002”>Unknown hotel identifier: 951357</error>
     </errors>
    </availabilityResponse>'
```

print this xml in xml format

Comment: You already printed it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = <<<XML
<availabilityResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <hotel id="123456789">
     <offers>
     <offer total="435.00" currency="EUR">
     </offer>
     </offers>
     </hotel>
     <errors>
     <error type="E002">Unknown hotel identifier: 32165487</error>
     <error type="E002">Unknown hotel identifier: 951357</error>
     </errors>
    </availabilityResponse>
XML;

header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

echo $xml->asXML();
```

This will output the xml file formated as xml.
You had an error in your xml though which i fixed. `<error type="E002">` must be in double-quotes it's xml-attribute.